# Is this a Model or a ViewModel?

Tags: design-patterns

In a **login screen**, a user may expose his `username` and `password` data. The same way, in a **user list screen**, it may expose user `name`, `age`, and `phone`. But none of this views may expose any other user information like `address` and some others.

I was under the idea that an entity (in this case, user) is the `Model` itself. And then, viewmodels would be used to expose properties depending on the case:

```
LoginViewModel
  - username
  - password

UserListViewModel
  - name
  - age
  - telephone
```

But in some cases I have seen these `ViewModels` called `Models` so I'm confused. Are these classes that expose certain properties called Model or ViewModels?

Comment: The idea of writing code like this predates the term "ViewModel", so a lot of people who got used to doing it before the term was invented still just call it a "Model".  See also Martin Fowler's description of the history of GUI patterns at http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.htm which gives interesting background for a lot of these ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, a view model is a type designed specifically for the view, the view model may aggregate multiple models or maybe show a subset of a single model. in the context of MVC the M stands for Model, but when working with business logic we also have models, so to be clear in the the M in MVC is the View Model where we have business models referenced from outside of our mvc application.